# Вывод данных в tableview javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Здраствуйте, только  начал изучать javafx да и java не так давно, поэтому не судите строго. Проблема следующая:  при выборе отдела в левой таблице у меня должны быть уникальные данные для каждого отдела в правой таблице. Данные пока что одинаковые, т. е. реализовано сейчас так, что они единственные для всех отделов сразу. Как static переменные, но мне нужно чтобы были уникальные для каждого отдела. 
Не пойму как это реализовать..Кнопка Delete у меня реализована и если удалить в одном отделе запись в правой таблице, то эта запись удалиться во всех отделах..

ссылка на гитхаб: https://github.com/ArabicCoffee/addressbook/tree/master

Класс Departmens содержит инфу об отделах и вложенный класс Person о контактах в правой таблице.

PersonOverview это контроллер, который загружает все в таблицы.

В MainApp в конструкоре у меня пока что статически забиваются начальные имена Отделов и получается для правой таблицы. Понимаю, что для правой таблицы этого делать не нужно, но как надо не знаю.

Подскажите хотя бы пожалуйста в каком направлении двигаться, как реализовать лучше и т п

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данные не должны повторяться внутри отдела или между отделами тоже?

Comment: должны быть уникальны между отделами. как в телефонной книге, в одном отделе свои сотрудники, в другом другие

Answer (score 0):

все, разобрался. надо было перенести массив в класс департамент.  а в классе PersonOverview я через ссылку на выбранный элемент в левой таблице загружал данные массива в правую